# getting Code Sign error when updating the application

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, app-store

I want to update my application in app sotre.... I again downloaded the Distribution certificate and distribution provision profile and try to build with that..
But its giving me error

Code Sign error: The identity 'iPhone Distribution: Mobilesoft LLC' doesn't match any valid certificate/private key pair in the default keychain.

At the time of submission i myself created the certificate. I want to ask if i create it again then build with new certificate does it effect anything if i update with the newly created certificate.

Thanx...

Comment: Are you doing everything from the same user account as before?

Comment: Yes..with the same user accout

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a new certificate and also create new provisioning profile with this new certificate and previous bundle identifier. It will work properly.

Answer (score 0):

You probably don't have the private key any more. If you can't find this, you can revoke and recreate your distribution certificate and provisioning profiles. This will not affect apps currently in the app store.